# i want to change pop up for paypal on checkout after click continue to paypal

Tags: magento2, checkout, paypal

i want to open pop up in new tab rather just showing in pop up.Can i change the width of Pop up.Plz help
https://ibb.co/iGMBPk

Answer (score 0):

Edit you PayPal setting:

Log into your Magento 2 Backend

Goto  Stores -> configuration -> sales -> payment methods ->  PayPal express checkout -> required PayPal settings -> express checkout  and search for the "enable in-context checkout experience" set it to "No"

After doing this possible clear your cache(I don't think you need to redeploy static content).

Customers should now be redirected to the PayPal website instead of seeing a pop-up. Keep in mind that this might not work or be legal in all regions as stated below the field "enable in-context checkout experience"

And have a nice day!

Further information:
Magento 2 documentation
http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/payment/paypal-in-context-checkout.html

PayPal documentation for in-context checkout
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/

Answer (score 0):

Go to

```
magento admin panel-> store-> configuration-> sales-> payments methods-> paypal-> configure
```

Now required

```
paypal setting-> express checkout-> Enable In-Context Checkout Experience (select no).
```

and you get what you want...!!!!